# Easy way to convert between c# date and sql datetime

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I keep having the same problem in my c# projects. I try to insert datetime to sql table, but in Turkey. the date is always DD.MM.YYYY,  C# or SQL sometimes try to insert MM.DD.YYYY like American way.

How do I solve this problem forever?

here is an example code

```
string selectSql = @"INSERT INTO [RN_VEHICLES_GUEST_INOUT] ([PLAKA],[MY_DATE])  
                     VALUES(@PLAKA,@MY_DATE)

cmd.Parameters.Add("@PLAKA", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@GELIS_TARIHI", SqlDbType.DateTime);

cmd.Parameters["@PLAKA"].Value = txtPlaka.Text.ToString();
cmd.Parameters["@GELIS_TARIHI"].Value = dateGelisTarihi.EditValue.ToString();
```

This code worked until today, It crashes today because today is 13.07.2013 and it tries to insert it as MM.DD.YYYY. yesterdat it was 12.07.2012 and I didnt have problem because it could convert 12 as a month but not 13. thats how I realized the problem.

How can I make sure C# and SQL always work in DD.MM.YYYY format?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's a `DateTime` field in database and a `DateTime` variable in C#, why do you convert it to a `String` at all?

So instead of

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@GELIS_TARIHI", SqlDbType.DateTime);
cmd.Parameters["@GELIS_TARIHI"].Value = dateGelisTarihi.EditValue.ToString();
```

just

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@GELIS_TARIHI", SqlDbType.DateTime);
cmd.Parameters["@GELIS_TARIHI"].Value = dateGelisTarihi.EditValue;
```

( assuming that `dateGelisTarihi.EditValue` is a `Dateime` )

Comment: yes you are right. it is an old habit. thank you very much. I will mark it as soon as possible